# Difference between WebApp that connects to API vs backend rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js, ajax

Sometimes when I create basic web tools, I will start with a nodeJS backend, typically creating an API server with ExpressJS. When certain routes are hit, the server responds by rendering the HTML from EJS using the live state of the connection and then sends it over to the browser.

This app will typically expose a directory for the public static resources and will serve those as well. I imagine this creates a lot of overhead for this form of web app, but I'm not sure.

---

Other times I will start with an API (which could be the exact same nodeJS structure, with no HTML rendering, just state management and API exposure) and I will build an Angular2 or other HTML web page that will connect to the API, load in information on load, and populate the data in the page.

These pages tend to rely on a lot of AJAX calls and jQuery in order to refresh angular components after a bunch of async callbacks get triggered. In this structure, I'll use a web server like Apache to serve all the files and define the routes, and the JS in the web pages will do the rest.

---

What are the overall strengths and weaknesses of both? And why should I use one strategy versus the other? Are they both viable and dependent upon scale and use? I imagine horizontal scaling with load balancers could work in both situations.

Answer (score 1):

There is no good or bad approach you could choose. Each of the approaches you described above have some advantages and you need to decide which one suits best to your project.

Some points that you might consider:

**Server-side processing**

- Security - You don't have to expose sensitive information (API tokens, logins etc).
- More control - You will have more control over what you do with your resources
- "Better" client support - Some clients (IE) do not support same things as the others. Rendering HTML on the server rather than manipulating it on client will give you more support for clients.
- It can be simpler to pre-render your resources on server rather than dealing with asynchronous approach on client.
- SEO, social sharing etc. - How your server sends resources, that's how bots see them. If you pre-render everything on the server bot will be able to scrape your site, tag it etc. If you do it on the client, it will just see non-processed page. That being said, there are ways to work around that.

**Client-side processing**

- Waiting times. Doing stuff on the client-side will improve your load times. But be careful not to do too many things since JS is single-threaded and heavy stuff will block your UI.
- CDN - you can serve static resources (HTML, CSS, JS etc) from CDN which will be much faster than serving them from your server app directly
- Testing - It is easy to mock backend server when testing your UI.
- Client is a front-end for particular application/device etc. The more logic you put into client, the more code you will have to replicate across different clients. Therefore if you plan to have mobile app, it will be better to have collection of APIs to call rather than including your logic in the client.
- Security - Whatever runs on the client can be fully read by the client. No matter how much you minify, compress, encrypt everything a resourceful person will always be able to do whatever they want with your code.

I did not mark pro/con on each point on purpose because it is up to you to decide which it is.

This list could go on and on, I didn't want to think about more points because it is very subjective, and in the end it depends on the developer and the application.

I personally tend to choose "client making ajax requests" approach or blend of both - pre-render something on the server and client takes care of rest. Be careful with the latter though as it will break your automated tests, IDE integration etc. if not implemented correctly.

Last note - You should **always** do crucial validations on the server. Never rely on data from client.

Comment: "Last note - You should always do crucial validations on the server. Never rely on data from client." is incredibly valuable and worth highlighting. Your answer is thorough. I will wait for any additional input before I accept your answer.